# How runloop by flag condition in R?

Tags: r

Suppose there is loop

```
x <- c(2,5,3,9,8,11,6)
count <- 0
for (val in x) {
if(val %% 2 == 0)  count = count+1
}
```

and there is flag  variable.
How to do that if `flag=TRUE` then run this loop and if flag has any other value then ignore run loop.Just continue to execute the rest of the code.

Comment: Before the loop `if(flag) { <loop code> }`. No need to explicitly test `flag == TRUE`, but if you have to, use `if(isTRUE(flag))`.

Comment: Also, the vectorized `count <- sum(x %% 2 == 0)`  is equivalent to your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several alternatives:

1. Don't loop if `!flag`:

   ```r
   flag <- FALSE
   x <- c(2,5,3,9,8,11,6)
   count <- 0
   if (flag) {
     for (val in x) {
       if(val %% 2 == 0)  count = count+1
     }
   }
   count
   # [1] 0
   ```
2. `break` out of the loop early:

   ```r
   flag <- FALSE
   x <- c(2,5,3,9,8,11,6)
   count <- 0
   for (val in x) {
     if (!flag) break
     if(val %% 2 == 0)  count = count+1
   }
   count
   # [1] 0
   ```
3. `while` loop, self-incrementing the loop, and break out if `!flag`. I'm not going to code this, since it adds no benefit to #1 yet adds the risk that unconstrained (if poorly-written) `while` loops can introduce.
4. Avoid the loop, do this directly:

   ```r
   flag <- FLASE
   sum(flag & x %% 2 == 0)
   # [1] 0

   flag <- TRUE
   sum(flag & x %% 2 == 0)
   # [1] 3
   ```